# Cannot convert Telerik RadRichTextBox content to HTML

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, richtextbox, telerik-mvc

I have been looking at Telerik Documentation and other web pages for hours just in order to convert Telerik RadRichTextBox content to HTML string but the only thing that can be useful is the following lines:

```
string ToHtml(RadDocument document) {
    return new HtmlFormatProvider().Export(document);
}
```

I tried to use this approach as shown below in order to convert myRichTextBox content but there is an error *"cannot convert from Telerik.WinForms.Documents.Model.RadDocument' to 'Telerik.WinControls.RichTextBox.Model.RadDocument"*

```
string text = new    HtmlFormatProvider().Export((Telerik.WinForms.Documents.Model.RadDocument)
myRichTextBox.Document)
```

I think I am missing something as creating Rad Document. Is there any way to achieve this? Any help please?

**Update :** Finally I have managed to convert the string to HTML format. However, I see that the richTextEditor cannot be formatted via Ribbon Bar control even if I set the richtextbox as "Associated control" for the Ribbon Bar. Any idea?

```
var textImporter = new TxtFormatProvider();
var document = textImporter.Import(rtMessage.Text ?? string.Empty);
string html = new HtmlFormatProvider().Export(document);
```

Comment: `WinForms` vs `WinControls`? They are not the same - and is this windows forms or asp.net-mvc?

Comment: See this reference: [Using HtmlFormatProvider](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/document-processing/libraries/radwordsprocessing/formats-and-conversion/html/htmlformatprovider). I can't see why you're using `Telerik.WinForms.Documents.Model.RadDocument` namespace there.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry Stephen, It is Windows Form application... On the other hand, I also tried with "Telerik.WinControls.RichTextBox.Model.RadDocument " but does not fix the problem.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks, but I had already look at that page and tried to last method, but I have no idea what to do instead of *CreateRadFlowDocument()*. Am I using wrong method from 4 of them?

Comment: Finally I have managed to convert the string to HTML format. @StephenMuecke However, I see that the richTextEditor cannot be formatted via Ribbon Bar control even if I set the richtextbox as "Associated control" for the Ribbon Bar. Any idea?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Could you pls have a look at update?

Comment: I also post the details on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49463621/telerik-radrichtextbox-text-cannot-be-formatted-via-radricheditorribbonbar